# Good panel interface component for C#?

Tags: c#, vb.net, user-interface, activex

Any nice **Paneled user interface** component COM/**ActiveX**/Source-code for **C#**/VB?

Like what VS has internally:

- Dock to screen edges
- Slide open/close (unpinned)
- Pin open
- Group in tabs

And if possible, **open-source**/free.

Well, because otherwise I'd have to develop an interface system myself.

Comment: You know you can mark your own questions as the accepted answer rather than closing them as no-longer relevant?

Comment: Wow! Yeah, I did'nt know that! Great new feature.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**[DockPanel Suite!](http://sourceforge.net/projects/dockpanelsuite/)** Its an open-source **docking library** for .NET Windows Forms development which **mimics Visual Studio .NET**.

Answer (score 1):

We use the DevExpress (devexpress.com) Component Suite, which has a Docking Manager that does that sort of thing.

Answer (score 1):

I've just been evaluating a few.

**Crownwoods DotNet Magic** *[(Discontinued Product)](http://www.dotnetmagic.com/)*
This has been around for a long time, and was initially one of the best docking managers out there, but its a bit long in the tooth now, we had quite a few crashes, it doesn't allow floating windows to be docked vertically and horizontally, and the tooltips on the tabs have a habit of hanging around.

**Telerik**
Visually great, but there a quite a few bugs in it, and its got a pretty big foot print (8MB). The event model is a bit difficult to work with as well. I integrated this into our application, only to discard the changes.

**Actipro**
I recon this is the best of the 3, it supports all the functionality you would expect, and I didn't come across any bugs. It doesn't look quite as good as the Telerik stuff, but at least it works properly, with a sensible object model and event structure.

Answer (score 0):

[OpenTheme](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/OpenTheme.aspx) is too fancy with styling support, but **not paneled.**